# Almost sure convergence of $\sqrt n$-truncated variables

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, probability-limit-theorems

Let $X_i$ be i.i.d. nonnegative random variables such that $E[X_1]<\infty$.

Is is true that

$$m_n:=\frac 1n \sum_{i=1}^n X_i1_{\{X_i \geq \sqrt n\}}$$

converges almost surely to $0$ ?

Since $$E\left[X_i1_{\{X_i \geq \sqrt n\}}\right] = E\left[X_11_{\{X_1 \geq \sqrt n\}}\right] \overset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow} 0$$ it is immediate that $m_n$ converges in $L^1$ to $0$, hence in probability as well.
Since $X_i$ has finite first moment, I know that $P(X_i \geq \sqrt n) = o(1/\sqrt n)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $R$ be a fixed integer; for each $n\geqslant R$,
$$
0\leqslant m_n\leqslant\frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\mathbf{1}_{\left\{X_i\geqslant \sqrt R\right\}}
$$
hence by the strong law of large numbers, the following inequality takes place almost surely:
$$0\leqslant 
\limsup_{n\to\infty}m_n\leqslant\mathbb E\left[X_1
\mathbf{1}_{\left\{X_1\geqslant \sqrt R\right\}}\right].
$$
Since $R$ is arbitrary, we can conclude.

Note that it would also work if we replace $m_n$ by $m'_n$ defined by
$$
m'_n=\frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\mathbf{1}_{\left\{X_i\geqslant R_n\right\}}
$$
where $\left(R_n\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ is a sequence of positive numbers such that $R_n\to\infty$, that is, $m'_n\to 0$ almost surely.

Comment: For fixed $R$, the convergence $\frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\mathbf{1}_{\left\{X_i\geqslant \sqrt R\right\}}$ to the mean happens on a set $\Omega_R$ of probability $1$ and the inequality $$0\leqslant 
\limsup_{n\to\infty}m_n\leqslant\mathbb E\left[X_1
\mathbf{1}_{\left\{X_1\geqslant \sqrt R\right\}}\right]$$ holds only $\Omega_R$. One should consider $\bigcap_{R\geq 1} \Omega_R$, which still has probability $1$. On this smaller set we have $$\forall R\geq 1, \quad 0\leqslant 
\limsup_{n\to\infty}m_n\leqslant\mathbb E\left[X_1
\mathbf{1}_{\left\{X_1\geqslant \sqrt R\right\}}\right].$$